# Escape syntax for LESS whilst using -ms-filter: "codeNeedsVar";

Tags: firefox, explorer, favorites

I needed to be able to get a less variable into

```
/* Opacity */
.opacity(@opacity: 0.35){
    -moz-opacity: @opacity;
    -khtml-opacity: @opacity;
    -webkit-opacity: @opacity;
    opacity: @opacity;
    @ieOpacity: @opacity * 100;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=@ieOpacity)";
    filter: ~"alpha(opacity=@ieOpacity)";
}
```

When this is complied the code would look like this in the .css file `(Opacity=@ieOpacity)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple, add `@{var}` so that less knows its a variable and not text

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=@{ieOpacity})";
```